# Excel update columns, cell values

Tags: excel

So here is what I am trying to do:

```
1) Look-up A2 value in Column C.
2) The rows in Column C where A:2 value exists, then the respective cell in D will get the value
   of B.  If it does not exists then D will have a value of 0.

the formula im using in D2 is something like =LOOKUP(A2,C:C,REPLACE WITH B) and if not exists then b2 = 0
```

I am able to use a match but dont know how to replace with the correct value

[image]

Comment: I suppose this is for superuser.com)

Comment: I am sorry If I posted the question at the wrong place. I will try there thanks.

Comment: no worries - I already flagged it, if moders think as I do - they'll will transfer it safely. I also provided an answer.

Comment: can you also remove the code formatting from your question? It makes reading the whole thing a lot harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the input correctly - you need a set of numbers incremented by 10 starting from certain number. There are 2 methods:

1. Put starting number, e.g. `10000000` in `A1`. In `A2` type the formula: `=A1+10` and autofill it down (or just copy and paste) for as many rows as you need.
2. Put `10000000` in `A1`, then `10000010` in `A2`, select **both** cells and drag using mouse for bottom right selection corner - this will produce incremented values.

Hope that was helpful.

**EDIT:**

After discussion in chat the solution is this (assuming uploaded screen sample):

1. Added row above the current data with zeros in A, B and C.
2. Column C: `1` in C3, `=C3+10` in C4 and autofilled, or simply values incremented by 10 starting 1: 1, 11, 21, ...
3. Column D: `=VLOOKUP(B2,A:C,3,0)` in D2 and down. This will return newly generated value from column C which corresponds to that value in A for the **same row**, i.e. for D5 it's 11, since B5 equals 1100000000, and this is A4 with corresponding 11 in C4.

All in all it looks like this:

[image: Sample]

Sample file is attached: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlc70q92oefiewe/IDsGeneration.xlsx

Comment: That works, I was able to increment the values starting from 1 in the first column. Its just how would I go about updating the second column. See if 100000 was replaced with 1 in A2. In B where 100000 was being used, How would I update B with the new ID which is 1.

Comment: @tamtam Could you please update your question with the sample of desired output?

Comment: I just updated the question with the desired output. Should I post the workbook if thats going to pinpoint the question correctly?

Comment: If I understand you correctly - you need just copy generated IDs and paste special them as values to target column.

Comment: yes thats correct. but once i update the first column with the incremental values, column b would not know what the old values should be replaced with. sorry if this is not clear

Comment: @tamtam sorry, in that case I still don't understand clearly what you need.

Comment: lets give it a last try, I put a screen shot. If we figure this out then fine but either way I will mark your answers as correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24588/discussion-between-peter-l-and-tam-tam)

Comment: @tamtam please enter chat using the link

Comment: Thank you buddy!  This works perfect. simple and elegant solution indeed.

Comment: @tamtam thanks for the challenge))) these were my hardest 25 rep points so far)